# Is it possible to get an Azure Storage account connection-string using the REST API?

Tags: azure

Is there any authorised API call I can make that would retrieve a connection string for a storage account?

e.g.

`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;AccountName=caestor1;AccountKey=<KEY>==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such there's no REST API to get the connection string for a storage account. This is something you will have to construct manually. You would need account key to construct the connection string and for that you can use [`List Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listkeys) REST API operation.